# ttf font not available for iPhone in interface builder or simulator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts, ios-simulator

I added a font file (.ttf) to my Xcode project, to resources. Also, I added it to the UIAppFonts in my info.plist.

When I want to use this font though, I don't even see it as a choice in IB.

After installing the font on my system, I started seeing it in IB, but still - changing to it doesn't change anything - some default system font is displayed in the Interface Builder as well as in iPhone emulator.

Are there any steps more I should do to be able to use my own font?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To use custom fonts with iOS you have to set them programmatically.

For example, suppose you have a font file called **swellfont.ttf** that you add to your project.
You then would go into your App-Info.plist file and add the full name of the file to the next index of the array keyed by UIAppFonts, as you mention.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>swellfont.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Then, to use the font:

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"swellfont" size:12];
```

Assuming that label is a **UILabel** and that **swellfont.ttf** is not [protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268747/custom-font-for-ipad-ios-3-2-isnt-working/4271356#4271356). It's important to note that UIFont's fontWithName is not referring to the filename, instead its wanting the actual name of the font. If you open the font with FontForge you can see this information by selecting Element > Font Info from the menu bar. There are probably cleverer ways to find this information out.

Comment: It should be noted that the string argument should be the font name not the filename for the font file (which may or may not be the same). That distinction had me spinning my wheels for a bit.

Comment: yep - I was adding that info as you commented. It also gave me quite a bit of issue. Kind of confusing! Apple's playing fast-and-loose with the definition of "name". :)

Comment: This is where I had been going wrong... Thanks to this it's now working. Thanks :D - 

It's important to note that UIFont's fontWithName is not referring to the filename, instead its wanting the actual name of the font.

Comment: I ran into a problem where the font wasn't available even after following these steps. I needed to add the font file to my Copy Bundle Resources Build Phase to have it included in the build.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I also had the same problem and had to add the fonts to 'Copy Bundle Resources' for it to work correctly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 fonts in an APP. The first one was automatically added to the "Copy Bundle Resources", the other was not. I had to add that one myself.

Call in code:

```
[labelName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OneGreatBigFont" size:40]];
```